# Radius of convergence - Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus

Given $f(x)$ a function that has derivatives of all orders in $\Bbb R$,

and $R_n(x)$ the $n^{th}$ order Lagrange form of the remainder,

Prove or disprove:

if $$lim_{x \to 0} {\frac {R_n(x)} {x^n}} = 0$$
for every $n$, than the radius of convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {f^{(n)}(0)} {n!} x^n$$
is larger than $\frac 12$.

My try:
Let 
$$a_n = \frac {f^{(n)}(0)} {n!}$$
By d'Alembert rule
$$R = lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac {a_n} {a_{n+1}}\right| = 
lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac {\frac {f^{(n)}(0)} {n!}} {\frac {f^{(n+1)}(0)} {(n+1)!}}\right| = $$
$$
 = lim_{n \to \infty} \left| 
\frac {f^{(n)}(0) \cdot  (n+1)!} {f^{(n+1)}(0) \cdot n!}
\right| = 
lim_{n \to \infty} \left| 
\frac {f^{(n)}(0) } {f^{(n+1)}(0) }\cdot  (n+1)
\right|
$$ 
stuck here.

Also tried Cauchy

$$\frac 1R = \overline {lim} \sqrt[n] {\left| a_n \right|} = 
\overline {lim} \sqrt[n] {\left| \frac {f^{(n)}(0)} {n!} \right|} = 
\overline {lim} 
\frac 
{
  \sqrt[n] {
        \left| 
           f^n(0)
        \right|
  }
} 
{
\sqrt[n] {n!}
} 
= ?
$$
again stuck.

Maybe the statement is false and there's a simple counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+100x^2}$.

**Remark:** The use of the term "Lagrange form of the remainder" is peculiar here, since whatever form we put it in, there is only one remainder $R_n(x)$.

Comment: great! how did you find it?

Comment: I wanted a series with a small radius of convergence. The standard ones are closely related to geometric series. So $\frac{1}{1-10x}$ would have been good, except for the unfortunate fact that it is not defined at $0$. But there is an easy fix, hence the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have found with your help even simpler example $ln(1+10x)$

Comment: You are welcome. The problem asks for derivatives of all orders on $\mathbb{R}$.  I assume this means **all** of $\mathbb{R}$. Your proposed example is not defined at $x=-1/10$, or at any $x\lt -1/10$. We can fix the $\lt -1/10$ part by taking absolute values, but we cannot fix the $-1/10$.